# Write to protected Excel File in C#

Tags: c#, excel

There is a file in which I want to write using C#, but I can't, I´ve checked for permissons and read-only properties of the file but they are not turned on. I'm trying something like this:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1;
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\template.xls");
xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkSheet1.Cells[1, 1] = "h1";
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
releaseObject(xlWorkSheet1);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
```

It works when I use any other file but when I use "template.xls" it just does nothing, there isn't errors, it appears to work good, but when I open the created file there is nothing new on it. my question is, Is there any permisson or rule that I'm forgeting?

Comment: Is the Workbook protected?  Does it have a password locking it from being edited?

Comment: What is the concrete exception you are getting. Is the file not being writable (i.e. another process may hold the file open and thus blocking write accesses of other processes), or is the Excel file protected (i.e., what DarkBobG was asking about)?

Comment: There aren't Exceptions, I've erased the try..catch sentences expecting an Exception and Nothing happend. It worked apparently fine but it didn't write anything new.

Comment: I am not sure since i lack experience with the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel classes, but it smells like "template.xls" is being protected - i am speaking about Excel document protection, not about file permissions/attributes. The Worksheet interface has a number of properties and methods related to document protection. Check the MSDN documentation, and debug/troubleshoot to see what the values of those properties are for "template.xls"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier solution, I copied the content of the file into a new file and it worked, I dont know why or How but it worked. Thanks for posting.